# How to write better else if condition by using less AND and OR logical operator?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have Client group logo and Client site logo. And want to assign Client site logo a value based on certain conditions.

This is my code in ClientController.cs :

```
if (site.ImageURL != null && site.ImageURL != "" && clientGroupImage != "/Content/Images/ClientLogoDefault.svg"
     && site.ImageURL != "/Content/Images/ClientSiteLogoDefault.svg" || site.ImageURL != null 
     && site.ImageURL != "" && clientGroupImage == "/Content/Images/ClientLogoDefault.svg" 
     && site.ImageURL != "/Content/Images/ClientSiteLogoDefault.svg")
     {
          model.SiteLogoURL = site.ImageURL;
     }
     else if (site.ImageURL == "/Content/Images/ClientSiteLogoDefault.svg" 
              && clientGroupImage != "/Content/Images/ClientLogoDefault.svg" || site.ImageURL == "" 
              && clientGroupImage != "/Content/Images/ClientLogoDefault.svg")
     {
          model.SiteLogoURL = clientGroupImage;
     }
     else
     {
          model.SiteLogoURL = "/Content/Images/ClientSiteLogoDefault.svg";
     }
```

So is there a way to write this code using less "&&" and "||" operators?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can do this;

- By writing boolean function for complex conditions, separate complex conditions from code to improve readability and ease of use. You can also re-use these functions for other similar scenarios.
- In your case, extract out string literals into variable or const strings. They will be easier to manage easier to read/use. Like Zaven Suggested.
- Nesting conditions when for cases there is common condition. Nesting is similar to if-then lingo.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool client = clientGroupImage == "/Content/Images/ClientLogoDefault.svg";
bool site = site.ImageURL == "/Content/Images/ClientSiteLogoDefault.svg";
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(site.ImageURL) && (!client && !site || client && !site)
{
   model.SiteLogoURL = site.ImageURL;
}
else if (!client && (site || site.ImageURL == "")
{
   model.SiteLogoURL = clientGroupImage;
}
else
{
   model.SiteLogoURL = "/Content/Images/ClientSiteLogoDefault.svg";
}
```

Comment: `(!client && !site || client && !site)` can be simplified to `!site`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional statements are not entirely clear, but in general you could treat compounded conditional statements (with AND and OR) a bit like math operators.

For example, in math you can do this: `A*B + A*C = A*(B+C)`
Now let treat A,B,C as simple conditions and assume * is AND and + is OR.
So `if ((A && B) OR (A && C))` can also be `if (A && (B OR C))`

For your specific case, I would need some clarifications about the first `if` statement, but I think you can do something like:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(site.ImageURL) && site.ImageURL != "/Content/Images/ClientSiteLogoDefault.svg" && 
    (clientGroupImage != "/Content/Images/ClientLogoDefault.svg" || clientGroupImage == "/Content/Images/ClientLogoDefault.svg"))
```

Seeing as the only difference is `clientGroupImage` condition, which if you notice will cover all cases, so you can drop this entirely.